# I want to make a remote webserver using raspberry pi contrplled by android app

Tags: php, android, python, apache, raspberry-pi

What code should i use in raspberry pi using python to implement this. I have done the client part.I have installed apache/php/mysql in my pi. What framework should i use here. Besides what part am i missing.I need to read/write to sensors through my pi. I have made an api hosted in a site which i have successfully tested in my app. Now i need to implement this in my pi remotely.

P.S.I don't know nothing about my pi.Should i write all my code in python(I prefer java), what libraries should i be using.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add that to use Python with Apache you'll have to enable mod_wsgi or mod_python or just write a standard CGI or FastCGI script.

I think bottle/flask supports all methods.

There is somewhere compiled JVM with support for hardware floating points, and that version should work a little better.

But, well, Raspberry Pi and Java aren't exactly friends.

I admit, it is a little odd, because we know that Java works perfectly fine on ARMs (e.g. Android), but current state for RasPi is as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Linux ([**`Raspbian`**](https://www.raspbian.org/)) running on your Raspberry Pi, as you may have on a regular PC, with the difference that the platform architecture is `ARM` as opposed to `x86`. So that means that you can run anything that is compiled on Linux for `ARM` architecture.

You may find `JVM` compiled for `ARM`, but it runs very heavy, and most Java web frameworks are also heavy.

However, Python comes built-in with Raspberry Pi, and there are a lot of libs written in Python for controlling Raspberry Pi peripherals. So Python is the best choice for you.

As for web frameworks, Python has number of lightweight ones, e.g.:

- [**`Pyramid`**](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/) - stable and light
- [**`Bottle`**](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) - new, super lightweight and very easy to use